# Variables in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I have only 1 column in my table, in this table there are inputs like 990x70, 980x50.
I need the values left and right of the 'x' to calculate inches of these 2 values. With this code I take only last registered entry from database. How can I get all entries?
*(Note: I have to use variables in this project.)*

```
   declare @Value1 numeric(18,1)
   declare @Value2 numeric(18,1)


   select 
   @Value2 = SUBSTRING(
       [Values], 
       CHARINDEX('x', [Values]) + 1, 
       LEN([Values])) ,

   @Value1 = SUBSTRING(
       [Values], 
       1, 
       CHARINDEX('x', [Values]) - 1)

   from myTable

   select @Value1=@Value1/(2.54)
   select @Value2=@Value2/(2.54)
   select @Value1,@Value2 from myTable
```

Edit: There are 4 different sizes in my table and I get the same result 4 times.
I want to get all results not only 1.

[image]

Comment: I guess this is homework. The first step in solving this is posting what your actual problem is. Do you get an error or do you get the wrong number?

Comment: Actually I've seen this homework question before and it's a typical question - it makes absolutely no sense to use variables in this case - see Matthews answer below.

Comment: The main issue here is that the database schema is not in [1NF (1st normal form)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form "see Wikipedia"), which can be seen from the fact that the OP has to split up values from one single column into several values.

Comment: It's a homework question so it bears no resemblance to the real world (including 1NF) unfortunately. It's an exercise in using string functions and variables.

Comment: First thing to understand is a variable is a `scalar`. It holds only one value. A table is not a scalar - it holds lots of values. So when you select a table (lots of values) into a scalar (only holds one value) it just remembers the last value. That's where your 78.7 is coming from. The your last statement selects this one scalar value for every record in the table. So it repeats it four times. That's whats going on in your code right now.

Answer (score 1):

Now, admittedly, I'm not totally clear on what you're asking. But it sounds like something like this should work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,1), SUBSTRING([Values], CHARINDEX('x', [Values]) + 1, LEN([Values]))) / 2.54,
       CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,1), SUBSTRING([Values], 1, CHARINDEX('x', [Values]) - 1)) / 2.54
FROM myTable
```

That should just do the same thing as you're doing, but without any of the variables (which are, in your usage, inherently one-dimensional).

Answer (score 0):

If you must use variables, start with this:

```
declare @Delimiter varchar(1) 
declare @CMtoInches DECIMAL(19,2)

Set @delimiter = 'x'
Set @CMtoInches = 2.54
```

and see if you can work out how to integrate it into Matthew's code.