# SQL returning the last registered result multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With this code i only get last registered result multiple times. I want to get all results.
this will be function.
(i have entries like 280x30, 360x40 at my table i need 2 numbers as variable to calculate inch value of these numbers)

```
declare @Value1 numeric(18,0)
declare @Value2 numeric(18,0)

select @Value2 = SUBSTRING([Values], CHARINDEX('x', [Values]) + 1, LEN([Values])) ,

@Value1 = SUBSTRING([Values], 1, CHARINDEX('x', [Values]) - 1),

@Value1=@Value1/(2.54),
@Value2=@Value2/(2.54)
from tblValues 

select @Value1 as Value1,
       @value2 as Value2
from tblValues
```

Comment: Why are you asking virtually the same question more than once? Duplicate of: [variables in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354296/variables-in-t-sql)

Comment: because i need a clear answer as soon as possible

Comment: You are approaching TSQL as if it was a programming language; but you simply have to query the table. Cease thinking in loopy iterations :)

Comment: btw: If you want the fastest possible answer provide `sample data` and `expected result`

Comment: @NonExperienced: You are not the only one who would like to have his problems solved quickly. However, that does not mean that you may ignore all rules and guidelines established on this site and described in the help center / FAQ. As a courtesy to all other SO users, please follow the rules. As Used_By_Already says, if you write a good, concise question that includes minimal sample data and desired result, you are actually making it easier for potential answerers to quickly give a good answer. Thanks for your  consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    tbl.Value1/2.54 AS Value1,
    tbl.Value2/2.54 AS Value2
FROM
(
    select 
        SUBSTRING([Values], CHARINDEX('x', [Values]) + 1, LEN([Values])) as Value2,
        SUBSTRING([Values], 1, CHARINDEX('x', [Values]) - 1) AS Value1
    from 
        tblValues
) AS tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

without the advantage of some data to play with.

You can use CROSS APPLY for reusable aliases, but not just that, you can use them to evaluate the conditions to help avoid errors. Not sure how consistent the input strings are but when converting strings to numbers almost anything can go wrong.

-- if you have sql 2012 or later use TRY_CAST()

```
SELECT
      TRY_CAST(ca2.Str1 AS numeric) / 2.54 AS Value1
    , TRY_CAST(ca2.Str2 AS numeric) / 2.54 AS Value2
FROM tblValues
      CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT
                        CHARINDEX('x', [Values])
            ) AS ca1 (pos1)
      CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT
                        CASE
                              WHEN pos1 > 1 THEN SUBSTRING([Values], ca1.pos1 + 1, LEN([Values])) END
                      , CASE
                              WHEN pos1 > 1 THEN SUBSTRING([Values], 1, ca1.pos1 - 1) END
            ) AS ca2 (Str1, Str2)
;
```

-- earlier versions use ISNUMERIC but that isn't perfect by any stretch

```
SELECT
      CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(ca2.Str1) THEN CAST(ca2.Str1 AS numeric) / 2.54 END AS Value1
    , CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(ca2.Str2) THEN CAST(ca2.Str2 AS numeric) / 2.54 END AS Value2
FROM tblValues
      CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT
                        CHARINDEX('x', [Values])
            ) AS ca1 (pos1)
      CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT
                        CASE
                              WHEN pos1 > 1 THEN SUBSTRING([Values], ca1.pos1 + 1, LEN([Values])) END
                      , CASE
                              WHEN pos1 > 1 THEN SUBSTRING([Values], 1, ca1.pos1 - 1) END
            ) AS ca2 (Str1, Str2)
;
```